# Bootstrap form problems

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a form where the user can input personal data. By pressing submit the form should be sent to a function that inputs the data in the database. I am using BOOTSTRAP to create the form, but for some reason I cant get to make it working.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="dataPost.php">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameInput" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Any suggestions why this is not working? Thanks

Comment: what does not-working mean?

Comment: @Lal
It was not inputing data in my DB. It is working now. Can't belive I actually forget to define the name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameInput" placeholder="Name">
```

You are not defining any name to it. Above code should look something like below:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surnameInput" id="surnameInput" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: Can't believe I forget the "name". Thanks for the heads up.